# Angular Google maps custom marker icon

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I cannot create a custom marker. Even though I am passing an image path to the icon parameter I am still getting the default orange marker. 
Please tell me if you see anything wrong.

**Directive's template:**

```
<div id="searchMap" class="googleMaps-destinations">
<div class="google-maps">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options">
        <ui-gmap-marker 
            ng-repeat="marker in search.origin_airports" 
            coords="marker.originMarker.location" 
            icon="marker.originMarker.icon.url" 
            fit="false" 
            idkey="'<< marker.originMarker.id >>'" >
        </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

I am using : //maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true with angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js

Comment: I just noticed that I cannot use animations as well.

Answer (score 14):

Missed that icon is an object.

```
 icon= '{url:    "//developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png" }'
```

Comment: that worked. But I don't think that what the doc says http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api

Answer (score 14):

I solved passing icon url through options property

Set something like this on controller

```
marker.options: {
    icon:'//developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png"'
}
```

and then

```
<div id="searchMap" class="googleMaps-destinations">
   <div class="google-maps">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options">
    <ui-gmap-marker
        options="marker.options" 
        ng-repeat="marker in search.origin_airports" 
        coords="marker.originMarker.location"      
        fit="false" 
        idkey="'<< marker.originMarker.id >>'">
    </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: Looks like this issue, of having to set the icon through the options hash, has been reported: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1408

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the custom icon problem
Check with **plunker** [Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/o4ItbQya7q7ahzxllEtg?p=preview)

```
options: {  draggable: false,      icon:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png' }
```

Html is here

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
        <ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
        </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```